# code in .htaccess does not redirect properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have following code in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.8mags\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://8mags.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It shows following error in firefox

```
The page isn't redirecting properly
```

This redirection code is written at the top of file.Below redirection code there is code for chaching and gzip compression and finally 404 redirect code

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://8mags.com/404page.html
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Do you have more rules in your htaccess? If yes then post them here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^8mags.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://8mags.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.html?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html?$ "/$1" [NC,R=301,NE,L]
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

I have implemented this similar code in my project.

Comment: I get redirected to http://8mags.com/404page.html There are two domain names hosted on this account could that be a problem?

Comment: No, it is not a reseller account